# Why didn’t the Jews appoint Aaron in place of Moshe

Tags: parashat-ki-tisa

When Moshe went “missing” on Har Sinai, why didn’t the Jews just appoint Aaron as the new leader? I mean he was clearly the second in command to Moshe, and he’d performed some of the plagues in Egypt so he had that miracle aspect to him, so why did the people choose a calf over the obvious option of Aaron?

Comment: They did appoint Aaron and he complied with their wishes and made them a golden calf, hoping to buy time until Moses came back.